# NSMutableArray does not print well with several lines of string

Tags: objective-c, sqlite

```
while(sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_ROW) {

  NSString *araci2 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)];

  [dbarray addObject:araci2];

  NSLog(@"DB ITEMS: %@",dbarray);

}
```

First of all, I try to get a description longer than a line from db. While part of the value appears meaningful, some of the characters of those values are absurd like "00fu". How can I print them in proper fashion ?

Comment: Can you paste an example?  And why aren't you using an objective-c wrapper for sqlite? it will make things SO much easier...

Comment: @Dave, a side question for you: which wrappers besides FMDB do you suggest?

Comment: @Jacob I've used this one before (http://th30z.netsons.org/2008/11/objective-c-sqlite-wrapper/), but FMDB is far and away my first choice.

Comment: can you print what `sqlite3_column_text(compiledStatement, 2)` returns before you pass the result to `NSString` ? Can you print what is in `araci2`? Are they all null terminated and they look as you would expect?

Comment: I can hold all of the values within dbarray. @stefanB And I printed the araci2, it prints well but when I wanted to print all of them as a dbarray, it prints like below: 



2010-04-22 10:51:31.815 MaSystemGui[13628:20b] HEPSI dbdesc (
 
"babam\U0131n di\U015fi a\U011fr\U0131d\U0131 bi g\U00fcn bu iyi geldi",

"gribe bire bir derler",
   
"G\U00fcnde 2 tane beyne iyi gelir",
   
"Valla ba\U011f\U0131\U015f\U0131kl\U0131k sistemini tavana kald\U0131r\U0131r \U00e7\U0131plak gezebilrisin buzullarda"

)

Comment: Addition to all above, I want to display value of dbarray in another view. I wrote below code into appropriate place. 

 [searchDetailViewController.animalDesciption setText:(NSString*)appDelegate.dbarray];


But it throws an exception when i clicked to some of items in tableview but not for all of them:

-[NSCFArray length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x3d21f40'

[Session started at 2010-04-22 11:10:36 +0300.]
2010-04-22 11:10:36.054 MaSystemGui[13711:20b] Stack: (
    8307803,
    2509790779,
    8689723,
    8259190,


I think NSMutableArray is really useless here

Answer (score 0):

I got over gentles. .. I created class and received those values by class variable.